# Use the same static file into multiple apps in Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

My Django project is divided into several apps, and the static files are stored in each app like this:

```
/Project
   /foo
      /static
         /css
            /style.css
      /views.py
      /models.py
      /urls.py
   /bar
      /static
         /css
            /style.css
      /views.py
      /models.py
      /urls.py
   /urls.py
   /manage.py
   /settings.py
```

But I am not sure how to use the same static files into multiple apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) setting is for:

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to
>   a particular app. The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is a tuple of
>   filesystem directories to check when loading static files. It’s a
>   search path that is by default empty.

Comment: So which style.css will be loaded in topic starter's case?

Comment: The above link doesn't exist anymore. Refer to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/ instead ... It is django's goto guide concerning referencing static files from different django apps.