# Which static file is loaded when two files have the same name?

Tags: django

Referring to a comment-question asked in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10068469/3790954), let's say I have two static files from two different apps that both have the same name `style.css`:

```
   /foo
      /static
         /css
            /style.css
      /views.py
      /models.py
      /urls.py
   /bar
      /static
         /css
            /style.css
      /views.py
      /models.py
      /urls.py
```

And I `manage.py collectstatic` all the files into `STATIC_ROOT`, what happens to `style.css`? How is precedence established for which `style.css` to load? How does each app's templates know which style.css to load?

I guess what I'm really asking is: what is the django best practice procedure for having static files with the same name in the same project?

Comment: The one found by the first loader.

Comment: Yes, and I know this can be verified by `findstatic`. What I'd like to know though is the proper procedure for managing identically-named files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in the tutorial docs of django. Link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial06/#customize-your-app-s-look-and-feel). Namespace your static files. Use the `{app_name}/static/{app_name}` convention like so.

```
/foo
  /static
    /foo # add this subdirectory
      /css
        /style.css
  /views.py
  /models.py
  /urls.py
/bar
  /static
    /bar # add this subdirectory
      /css
        /style.css
  /views.py
  /models.py
  /urls.py
```

This way you can have identical filenames. You can now refer to these files as foo/css/style.css and bar/css/style.css in `{% static %}` tags. The URLs would then be {STATIC_ROOT}/foo/css/style.css and {STATIC_ROOT}/bar/css/style.css.